# How to do back selector same as android market UI?

Tags: android, android-layout

How to do this kind of events

when I pressed the Preferences Button I need to change only the background color of the arrow.

[image]

what I did is when I put
 `android:background="@null"` for TextView is not working showing the whole view with blue color background.

```
<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_selector"
                android:clickable="true" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/back_arrow"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_ab_back_holo_dark" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/settings_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:background="@null" 
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/back_arrow"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="@string/settings_title"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="22sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the textview normally, black background (#000000) and have an imageButton set the src as a drawable selector:

```
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@null" android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
         android:paddingLeft="50dp" android:paddingTop="25dp" android:src="@drawable/button_selector"/>
```

selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="false"
            android:drawable="@drawable/button_rested"/>
    <item android:state_enabled="false"
            android:drawable="@drawable/button_disabled"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the state list drawable for the background of the ImageView( or change to button if you like). then you can set the background of the button in different state ( for example, when pressed).

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList)